# PostgreSQL returns Copy 0 for a csv file

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I have a test csv file with 2 lines that consists of 7 fields integrated with django. Apart from that, I have another test csv file with an obvious error in it (random delimiters).
The query in pgAdmin is the following:
COPY public.website_manager_tasks FROM 'C:\upwego_test\csvs\tasks.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER;
The csv text is the following:

```html
'id';'textbook_code'|'task_type'|'task_text'|'question_number'|'question_text'|'answer'
1;'WP'|'gapfilling'|'Choose the right synonym for the underlined word.'|1|'It is hard for someone with an ... 1) preference 2) fear 3) ignorance'|1
2;'WP'|'gapfilling'|'Choose the right synonym for the underlined word.'|2|'The short-story ... 1) new 2) old 3) different'|1
```

No extra spaces, strings have quotation marks, the delimiter is set properly, data types match, the name of the file doesn't match any columns.

In the second csv file, the delimiters are set improperly: ; | | | | | However, the data from this csv file copies perfectly. I don't understand the postgre's problem here.

I have tried changing the resetting the delimiters in the first csv file so that they matched the pattern in the second csv file, and it didn't help. I also tried to copy the text from the first csv file to the second csv file and everything worked perfectly.

I have no idea why it happens so. I'd be glad if anyone could explain this glitch and am ready to provide additional details.

Comment: 1) That is not a database it is a table 2) **Do not** use images. Copy and paste as text the data into your question 3) What you show in the image looks like a CSV file not a table or database, is that correct? 4) What client are you using to view the data? **ADD preceeding** as update to question.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Yes, that's a csv file. I use pgAdmin to interact with everything. Added everything to the question. Thanks!